# Autocad format to WEB format

Tags: javascript, browser, autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk-viewer

Is there a way to convert format autocad (.dwg, .dxf) to web format, then we can see in any web-browser? and work with javascript, any information is welcome

Comment: In simple words yes, if you want to pay a comercial solution..(https://www.canvasgfx.com/ fpr example) There are a few but not cheap ones. There is no free dwg to canvas thing out. If you own autocad, you can write something which will convert all drawing entitys to something which a 2d or 3d JS Lib will understand. But that will take some afford also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
You need to use [Model Derivative service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) to translate a AutoCAD drawing file to viewable format SVF.

There is blog on [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-tutorial-nodejs)

Refer - https://github.com/libvarun/DA-Sample-with-Viewer